# When my bot DMs a user, how do i get it's next message with discord.py (within DMs)

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm working on a bot. When you say `r!report`, it DMs the user asking for some infos such as username, reason, attachment one by one.

So when my bot DMs a user, how would I get the next message the user sends after my bot's DMs, and store it and then create an embed with all the info they gave? I can do the embed, but I don't seem to be find a way to check the message.

Also if you could include how to get a png/jpg file they send in DMs, how would I store it?

https://gyazo.com/7aedd5d89dc54fc48ec6b63cd34d9024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wait_for`

```py
@bot.command()
async def whatever(ctx):
    def check(message: discord.Message):
         """Checks if the channel where the message was sent is DM
         and if the author of the message is the same as the invoker of the command"""
         return isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel) and message.author == ctx.author

    await ctx.author.send("Hello! Please reply to this message")
    message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check) # You can also add a timeout, read the docs for it

    print(f"{ctx.author} replied: {message.content}")
```

To get a files from messages you can simply use the `Message.attachments` attribute

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(ID) # This is just for testing

# Looping through every attachment in the message
for attch in message.attachments:
    f = await attch.to_file() # Returns a `discord.File` instance, NOTE: this does NOT save the file, to save it use `Attachment.save`

    # Sending the file
    await channel.send(file=f)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Bot.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)
- [`Message.attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20attachments#discord.Message.attachments)
- [`Attachment.to_file`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=to_file#discord.Attachment.to_file)
- [`Attachment.save`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=attachment%20save#discord.Attachment.save)